# Scroll to position on canvas with react-konva

Tags: html5-canvas, react-konva

I have a react-konva that displays a large/tall image, something like:

```
<div>
  <Stage>
    <Layer listening={false}>
      <img src=‘...’>
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
</div>
```

The image is tall enough to require scrolling. I want to add a button that will scroll halfway down in the canvas. When I inspect the elements in my browser, the only element that has a height is a  added by react-konva with a class of `.konvajs-content`. I've tried scrolling on the div wrapper, but that is not working. What is the best way to about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some elements in the canvas (like Rect, Circle, Image,...) must have positions(x and y) and dimensions (width and height) to be shown and drawn on the canvas. So first of all to display an image on the canvas with `react-konva` library I suggest you use `Image` element which can be imported from the library. to see actual use please see this reference: https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Images.html

In the end, for your scroll problem, I hope this example helps you: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_Scrolling.html